# Использование get / set в string с фиксированным размером в структурах

Tags: c#, структуры, строки, get

Добрый вечер.

Есть структура:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
struct MyStruct
{
    public int Var1 { get; set; }
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
    public string Var2;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
    public string Var3;
    public int Var4 { get; set; }
};
```

Нужно добавить get и set методы для Var2 и Var3, при этом **не изменив** размер структуры - т.е. без дополнительных членов в структуре.

Ошибка компилятора:

> error CS0592: Attribute 'MarshalAs' is
> not valid on this declaration type. It
> is only valid on 'field, param,
> return' declarations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самый очевидный вариант разграничить свойства и поля:

```
struct MyStruct2
{
    public int Var1 { get; set; }

    public string Var2
    {
        get { return _var2; }
        set { _var3 = value; }
    }

    public string Var3
    {
        get { return _var3; }
        set { _var3 = value; }
    }
    public int Var4 { get; set; }

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
    private string _var2;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
    private string _var3;
};
```

Это добавит два свойства(то есть 4 метода), но фактически не поменяет размер самой структуры:

```
Console.WriteLine(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MyStruct)));  // 72
Console.WriteLine(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MyStruct2))); // 72
```

Comment: Поскольку порядок полей скорее всего важен, я бы утащил `Var4` в конец структуры.

Comment: Да, LayoutKind.Sequential на это намекает.